# Copernicus ERA5 crs/projecition for NetCDF

Tags: r, copernicus, stars

i'm trying to work from netCDF from this link:

https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/reanalysis-era5-single-levels?tab=form

but i can't find the correct EPSG.

In documentation page i found that :

> If you request the data in NetCDF format, it is automatically converted and interpolated from the above grids to a regular lat/lon grid.

So i try to open it as WGS84 Lat/Lon but when i try to view under another layer i obtain something like this
[image]

Comment: It's in longitude range 0-360 rather than -180 to +180. There have definitely been earlier questions about this, but I'm not sure if there was a specific netCDF one.